# can't change text javascript

Tags: javascript, text

I tried to make an animation on javascript.

It should look like:

Frame 1:

`ඞ______ _`

Frame 2:

`_ඞ_____ _`

Frame 3:

`__ඞ____ _`

Frame 4:

`___ඞ___ _`

I want to something that changes the text after some seconds. So I've got a label and this is a snippet of a code.

`document.getElementById('label').innerHTML='ඞ______ _';`

`sleep(500);`

But if I use the sleep function, the page 'waits' until my 'animation' is finished and then I can see the last text:

`___ඞ___ _`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Post your [mcve] please

Comment: Why don't you use interval?

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval is what you want to use. Sleep methods typically just lock up the browser....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a `async function` for updating the animation at the same time of doing the other stuff your javascript is doing.

an `async function` looks like this

```
async renderAnimation () {
    setTimeout(() => {this.animate() }, 500);  
}

animate(){
    document.getElementById('label').innerHTML='ඞ______ _';
}
```

You should check this link for a more in deep explanation of async: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

Comment: async makes no difference here. There is nothing awaiting.... If you had a linter on this the would be throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code your thing to use an interval or timeout.

```js
function annimateText(elem, frames, ms) {

  let index = 0;
  let timer;
  
  const stop = () => window.clearTimeout(timer);
  
  const update = () => {
    elem.textContent = frames[index];
    index++;
    if (frames.length <= index) stop();
  };

  timer = window.setInterval(update, ms);
  
  update();

  return {
    stop: timer,
  };
}


const frames = [
  "ඞ______ _",
  "_ඞ_____ _",
  "__ඞ____ _",
  "___ඞ___ _",
  "____ඞ__ _",
  "_____ඞ_ _",
  "______ඞ _",
  "_______ඞ_",
]
annimateText(document.querySelector("#out"), frames, 100);
```

```css
#out {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
```

Now can you do sleeps? Yes you can do it with async and await.

```js
async function outputAndWait (text) {
  document.querySelector("#out").textContent = text;
  await sleep(100);
}

async function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function animateIt () {
  await outputAndWait("ඞ______ _");
  await outputAndWait("_ඞ_____ _");
  await outputAndWait("__ඞ____ _");
  await outputAndWait("___ඞ___ _");
  await outputAndWait("____ඞ__ _");
  await outputAndWait("_____ඞ_ _");
  await outputAndWait("______ඞ _");
  await outputAndWait("_______ඞ_");
}

animateIt();
```

```css
#out {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
```